# struct templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I've learned about function templates, class templates, templates specialization but now I've came across this example which blows everything else out of the water because it's so different from the other uses I just can't understand how it was used in this example :

```
template <int n> struct Fibo
{
    static int val; 
};

template <> int Fibo<0>::val = 1;

template <> int Fibo<1>::val = 1;

template <int n> int Fibo<n>::val = Fibo<n-1>::val + Fibo<n-2>::val;

int CalcFibo(int n)
{ 
    return Fibo<n>::val;
}
```

Not sure I understand what was done here (of-course I can see it's fibonacci related, but the way it was used compared to class templates or function templates.. I just can't understand what's going on in here and I would be thankful if someone could help me understand)

Comment: There's currently no relation to your template parameter `n` in `Fibo`?

Comment: template metaprogramming: http://milotshala.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/fibonacci-sequence-and-c-template-meta-programming/

Comment: Generating Fibonacci numbers is the canonical demonstration of C++ metaprogramming, Google for "C++ template fibonacci" will give you millions of hits.

Comment: It computes Fibbonacci number at compile time, but your `CalcFibo` will not work, since `n` must be known at compile time, eg: `Fibo<6>::val`

Comment: As Rafael noted, this doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `struct` templates and `class` templates, except the difference between `struct`s and `class`es themselves (i.e. all members in structs are public by default, and all members in classes are private by default.)

This classic example of **template metaprogramming** is not specific to `struct`s; it can as easily be accomplished using classes as well. You just need a bit more typing to specify that the `val` member is `public`.

As noted in the comments on your question, your code won't compile. The problem is in the `CalcFibo` function, where you are using a runtime value (the parameter `n`) to instantiate a template, which always requires a value that is known at compile-time. You can change your "function" to something like this:

```
template <int N> int CalcFibo () {return Fibo<N>::val;}
```

But I doubt that it's what you want.